# Folder crashed when i push to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I have problem pushing my local folder to git repository using Bitbucket.
Using terminal i switch to the directory when my project folder is and i use the following commands:

1. git init
2. git add
3. git commit -m "new commit"
4. git remote add origin https://.....
5. git push origin master

And after i succeed this and it tells me that the folder is added to my repository i get the folders like on the attached picture.

Can someone help why is it like this?

Thank you,
Igor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIQwM.png)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors from the Git bash?  If something went seriously wrong, you'd see it there.

Comment: Not really. I succeed push my files to bitbucket repository but not inside the folder, so when you go to source the files are there, when i am adding in folder happens this. Maybe you  have any solution how to push a folder with files in existing repository?
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: You can see it in the picture how the pushed folders looks like.

Comment: Those things look like submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add .gitignore file in the Project Folder and repeat the git commands and the folder was added to the repository with all files inside.